# How do I get rid of these added "windows"?

Tags: interface, osx

[image: blender with the duplicated windows highlighted]

I accidentally created far too many of these window-type things. It's literally the same view like 5 times... (I don't know what they are called - I apologize!)

How do I get rid of them?